# PayPal integration in asp.net but I want no real money only for presentation in university

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on a university project and I must deal with online payment, so I search for that and then I get a PayPal Express Checkout.

I am assuming that this method works on real credit card number, but I want only for demo. How can I deal with this?

Comment: You need real credit card only, if you don't want to spend much, do small transaction between own (2) account. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a test account [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts) (paypal developer site) and take a look to the [testing guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/).
Instead of PayPal you can also use [stripe.com](https://stripe.com) that it's much more easier to implement than PayPal

Answer (score 0):

you should look into sandbox.paypal.com 
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts?event=createSuccess

I think that's what you want, you can create accounts for testing, for both regular and business users

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the sandbox version of Paypal for developers.

Have a look in here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/